# Why my custom ToolbarExtension is not registred when I initialize two viewers? (with one works)

Tags: autodesk-viewer, autodesk

I have a custom extension that add 3 buttons in the default viewer toolbar, they were working just fine but now I have to initialize two viewers in my app, for in future, load a model in it, and now I'm receiving this error:

`Uncaught (in promise) Extension not found: ToolbarExtension. Has it been registered(1)?`

Yes it's registred (I was using it before).

[image: register extension lines]

[image: loading extension]

It's curious because if I remove the `ToolbarExtension` from the extensions array and call somewhere in code `await viewer.loadExtension("ToolbarExtension")`, it works, but I don't want to do this because it has a delay to execute and I want to work as previously

Obs: Only the main viewer is initialized with extensions and if I remove the second viewer initialization the error's gone and it works perfectely.

Answer (score 0):

I put together the following quick test, and I'm able to load the same extension in both viewers:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/style.css">
    <script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/viewer3D.js"></script>
</head>

<body style="margin: 0; height: 100vh;">
    <div id="viewer1" style="position: absolute; left: 0; right: 0; top: 0; height: 50%;"></div>
    <div id="viewer2" style="position: absolute; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; height: 50%;"></div>
    <script>
        class MyExtension extends Autodesk.Viewing.Extension {
            constructor(viewer, options) {
                super(viewer, options);
            }

            load() {
                return true;
            }

            unload() {
                return true;
            }

            onToolbarCreated() {
                let group = this.viewer.toolbar.getControl('my-toolbar-group');
                if (!group) {
                    group = new Autodesk.Viewing.UI.ControlGroup('my-toolbar-group');
                    this.viewer.toolbar.addControl(group);
                }
                const button = new Autodesk.Viewing.UI.Button('my-button');
                button.setToolTip('My Button');
                button.onClick = () => alert('Hello World!');
                group.addControl(button);
            }
        }

        Autodesk.Viewing.theExtensionManager.registerExtension('MyExtension', MyExtension);

        Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer({ env: 'Local' }, function () {
            const config = {
                extensions: ['MyExtension']
            };
            const viewer1 = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(document.getElementById('viewer1'), config);
            viewer1.start();
            // Load some URN into viewer1
            const viewer2 = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(document.getElementById('viewer2'), config);
            viewer2.start();
            // Load some URN into viewer2
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Perhaps there's something else in your code that's causing this issue?

Comment: Thank u for your help Petr, I don't know whats wrong, but I solved this by putting the <script> custom extension tag above the viewer script tag, I tried to post an answer but Stack over didn't allow, sorry for your wasted time.